# MSSQL / PHP - assistance with query and resultset to get data for bar chart

Tags: php, sql-server

I am trying to create a bar chart that shows monthly hits for the past 12 months.

I have the below query:

```
SELECT 
      (MONTH(date)) AS MONTH
    , (YEAR(date)) AS YEAR
    , SUM(hits) AS count 
FROM [statistics]
WHERE ID = '". $id ."' 
    AND (date > DATEADD(yy, - 1, GETDATE())) 
GROUP BY (MONTH(date)), (YEAR(date)) 
ORDER BY year, month
```

This provides the below resultset:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Admin] => Array
                (
                    [month] => 7
                    [year] => 2012
                    [count] => 702
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Admin] => Array
                (
                    [month] => 8
                    [year] => 2012
                    [count] => 650
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [Admin] => Array
                (
                    [month] => 9
                    [year] => 2012
                    [count] => 670
                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [Admin] => Array
                (
                    [month] => 10
                    [year] => 2012
                    [count] => 66
                )

        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [Admin] => Array
                (
                    [month] => 11
                    [year] => 2012
                    [count] => 53
                )

        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [Admin] => Array
                (
                    [month] => 12
                    [year] => 2012
                    [count] => 39
                )

        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [Admin] => Array
                (
                    [month] => 1
                    [year] => 2013
                    [count] => 54
                )

        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [Admin] => Array
                (
                    [month] => 2
                    [year] => 2013
                    [count] => 36
                )

        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [Admin] => Array
                (
                    [month] => 3
                    [year] => 2013
                    [count] => 48
                )
        )
)
```

This only shows the months that it has results for but I need all months whether they have results or not (so count would be 0). What I need is something more like the below which includes all 12 months:

```
   Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [Admin] => Array
                    (
                        [month] => 7
                        [year] => 2012
                        [count] => 702
                    )

            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [Admin] => Array
                    (
                        [month] => 8
                        [year] => 2012
                        [count] => 650
                    )

            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [Admin] => Array
                    (
                        [month] => 9
                        [year] => 2012
                        [count] => 670
                    )

            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [Admin] => Array
                    (
                        [month] => 10
                        [year] => 2012
                        [count] => 66
                    )

            )

        [4] => Array
            (
                [Admin] => Array
                    (
                        [month] => 11
                        [year] => 2012
                        [count] => 53
                    )

            )

        [5] => Array
            (
                [Admin] => Array
                    (
                        [month] => 12
                        [year] => 2012
                        [count] => 39
                    )

            )

        [6] => Array
            (
                [Admin] => Array
                    (
                        [month] => 1
                        [year] => 2013
                        [count] => 54
                    )

            )

        [7] => Array
            (
                [Admin] => Array
                    (
                        [month] => 2
                        [year] => 2013
                        [count] => 36
                    )

            )

        [8] => Array
            (
                [Admin] => Array
                    (
                        [month] => 3
                        [year] => 2013
                        [count] => 48
                    )
            )
        [9] => Array
            (
                [Admin] => Array
                    (
                        [month] => 4
                        [year] => 2013
                        [count] => 0
                    )
            )
        [10] => Array
            (
                [Admin] => Array
                    (
                        [month] => 5
                        [year] => 2013
                        [count] => 0
                    )
            )
        [11] => Array
            (
                [Admin] => Array
                    (
                        [month] => 6
                        [year] => 2013
                        [count] => 0
                    )
            )
    )
```

Can anyone suggest which would be the best way to achieve this?  Could it be done in the SQL or does it need to be done in the code?  If so, how?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: No, changes needs to be in the code. Do you want results to be displayed as table ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved through PHP using a loop which iterates all the possible months, and if there is data for that month, add it to an output array, otherwise, insert a blank entry with count of 0 for that month

**EDIT**
Example solution;

```
$m = $resultset[0]['Admin']['month'];
$y = $resultset[0]['Admin']['year'];
for ($i = 0; $i < 12; $i++) {
    $adj = ((($i - 1) + $m) % 12) + 1;
    if (!(isset($resultset[$i]['Admin']['month']) && $resultset[$i]['Admin']['month'] == $adj)) {
        array_splice($resultset, $i, 0, array(array(
            'Admin' => array(
                'month' => $adj,
                'year'  => $y + ($i + $m > 12),
                'count' => 0
            )
        )));
    }
}
```

The important part for solving your issue is the line;

```
$adj = ((($i - 1) + $m) % 12) + 1;
```

This translates `$i` from being an integer between 0-11 to a month between 1-12, depending on the starting month (`$m`)

Comment: Yes that's what I thought but am struggling with getting the months in order.  It needs to be the past 12 months not just months 1 to 12, ie. July 2012 to June 2013

Comment: Was a bit trickier than I'd first imagined, but I've come up with some example code :P

Comment: Wow, Id have never have got that, just don't have the brain power, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well try this code it may help

```
foreach ($array as $year => $values) {

        for ($i = 1; $i <= 12; $i++) { // Loop through months 1 .. 12

                if (!$values[$i]) {
                        echo "0";
                } else {
                        echo $values[$i];
                }
        }
}
```

Comment: My array key doesn't refer to the year so this wont work I don't think.  I just get "undefined offset"